# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n 2^{n-1}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to find $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n 2^{n-1}}}$$

**Attempt:**

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^n} = \frac{x}{2-x}$$

Which is just evaluating geometric series

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)2^{n}}$$

Now, by finding antiderivative of $\frac{x}{2-x}$

$$f(x) = -x-2\ln(x-2)$$

Finding sum should be just $$S = 1 + f(1)$$

But $f(x)$ is undefined as a real-valued function for $x \leq 2$

Comment: Is there an absolute value symbol missing from inside the logarithm, after integrating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$. Then the sum that you're after is $2f\left(\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

An antiderivative for $\frac x {2-x}$ for $x<2$ is $-x-2\log(2-x)$ as you can see by diffferentiation. You  missed an absolute value sign  when you found the antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{z^n}{n}=-\ln(1-z)$, $S=-2\ln\left(1-\frac12\right)=\ln 4$.

Answer (score 1):

$$S=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-n}}{n}=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}~ 2^{-n} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} ~dx=2 \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{x} \frac{x/2}{1-x/2} ~dx=2 \ln 2. $$